# Is it possible to convert large double number to big decimal without losing precision when deserializing a json data?

Tags: java, json, type-conversion, double, data-conversion

Customer sends me a json double data like
"amount": 123345555789123495.38
and in our program we get the whole message and program get the value like 1.23345555789123488E17
Is it possible to convert this data right with precision??

@JsonProperty("map")
private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> extensionMap;

I tried
new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(map.get("amount"))).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);

Output is:
123345555789123488.00

Comment: If `amount` is a double, converting it to BigDecimal won't recover lost precision. You would have to parse as a String or BigDecimal in the first place. What JSON library are you using?

Comment: @shmosel I believe I'm using  jackson library

Comment: Try using a proper POJO instead of the Map and declaring the `amount` field as BigDecimal.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import static java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_UP;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonAmount = "123345555789123495.38";
        BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(jsonAmount).setScale(2, HALF_UP);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is I don't get the amount value as string